# Restore GridView data after orientation change

Tags: android, android-orientation

I'm using GridView to load dynamically data to my Activity:

```
private ArticuloAdapter articuloAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_articulos);

    // get ListaArticulos from the database

    articuloAdapter = new ArticuloAdapter(this,R.layout.lista_articulo, ListaArticulos);
    grdArticulos.setAdapter(articuloAdapter);  
}
```

And I want to restore the data after a orientation change:

```
ArrayList<String> articulosBackup = new ArrayList<String>();   

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);            
    int size = grdArticulos.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) this.grdArticulos.getChildAt(i);
        ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) layout.getChildAt(1);     

        EditText et =(EditText)gridChild.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.Cantidad);           
        EditText et2 = (EditText)gridChild.getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.jaulas);           
        EditText et3 =(EditText)gridChild.getChildAt(2).findViewById(R.id.contenedores);          
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gridChild.getChildAt(3).findViewById(R.id.manipulado);

        String dato = et.getText().toString() + ":" + et2.getText().toString() + ":" + et3.getText().toString() + ":" + String.valueOf(cb.isChecked());
        articulosBackup.add(dato);
    }
    outState.putSerializable("articulosBackup", articulosBackup);   
    outState.putInt("items", size);
}
```

I am saving the data in an ArrayList like strings with the format: data1:data2:data3:data4.
That works nice. But now when I try to restore them I got NullPointerException in the line that is commented:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);   

    articulosBackup = (ArrayList<String>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("articulosBackup"); 
    items           = savedInstanceState.getInt("items");      

    if (articulosBackup != null) {          
        for(int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
            ViewGroup layout    = (ViewGroup) grdArticulos.getChildAt(i);
            ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) layout.getChildAt(1); // NULLPOINTEREXECPTION: layout variable is null

            String datos[] = articulosBackup.get(i).split(":");

            // Cantidad
            EditText et =(EditText)gridChild.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.Cantidad);
            et.setText(datos[0]);

            // Jaulas
            EditText et2 = (EditText)gridChild.getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.jaulas);
            et2.setText(datos[1]);

            // Contenedores
            EditText et3 =(EditText)gridChild.getChildAt(2).findViewById(R.id.contenedores);
            et3.setText(datos[2]);

            //  Manipulado
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gridChild.getChildAt(3).findViewById(R.id.manipulado);
            cb.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(datos[3]));
        }
    } 
}
```

So my question is: How I can restore my dynamic GridView after the orientation change? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of saving and restoring should be used for small data say for primitive values. For large sets of data like arraylist, data base you should override onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and return the object.

Caution: While you can return any object, you should never pass an object that is tied to the Activity, such as a Drawable, an Adapter, a View or any other object that's associated with a Context. If you do, it will leak all the views and resources of the original activity instance. (Leaking resources means that your application maintains a hold on them and they cannot be garbage-collected, so lots of memory can be lost).

You should override onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and return the arraylist.

For more information have a look at the link here. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {

return arraylist;//return arraylist
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

final ArrayList data = (ArrayList ) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
if (data == null) { //if data is null populate data to arraylist.
 //do something  
}
// use arraylist
}
```

Once orientation changes activity is recreated. So return the value in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(). In onCreate() supply the value returned.

Example:

```
       @Override
   public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {

   return mPostingData; 
   }
```

In onCreate()

```
   final ArrayList data = (ArrayList) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
      if (data == null) {
          System.out.println("data is null");
      //populate arraylist with values.
      }
      else
      {
           for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
           System.out.println("data is not null..."+data.get(i)); 
      }
```

Comment: Thank, I've implemented your solution but the GridView does not load the data I've stored. The arrayList saves the data perfectly.

Comment: @enrmarc. Once arraylist saves data , final ArrayList data = (ArrayList ) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();. The data is the returned arraylist. if its null load again. if not use the same

Comment: Sorry, my `ArticuloAdapter` was wrong (it was not setting the data). Thank you very much.